# Load CSV in BQ via command line

Tags: csv, google-bigquery

ive been trying to load a csv file in bigquery using this command and i keep getting error. My csv file looks like this, my file has total 40 rows only including the header. I get the same error when i tried to load the csv file using the console gui

```
header 1,header 2,Header 3,Header 4,Header 5,Header 6,header 7,Header 8,header 9,Header 10 
Justine,Mobile,Address,Location,2020-01-26,1,0,11,3,1
```

With this command line:

```
bq load --allow_jagged_rows=1 --skip_leading_rows=1 --source_format=CSV  datasetId.mytableid /home/username/file.csv
```

And I got this error

```
Upload complete.
Waiting on bqjob_r421ecc680c644b1b_0000016fdb99efe1_1 ... (1s) Current status: DONE   
BigQuery error in load operation: Error processing job 'my-project-id:bqjob_r4212fs8997c644b1b_000db99efe1_1': Error while reading data, error message: CSV table encountered too many errors,
giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details.
Failure details:
- Error while reading data, error message: Error detected while
parsing row starting at position: 309. Error: Bad character (ASCII
0) encountered.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
bq load --source_format=CSV project_id:dataset.tablename /PATH_TO_FILE/airports.csv IATA:STRING,AIRPORT:STRING,CITY:STRING,STATE:STRING,COUNTRY:STRING,LATITUDE:FLOAT64,LONGITUDE:FLOAT64
```

I simply removed the first row (the header) from the CVS as I have already mentioned the schema and datatype in the command. I then run the above command and it created the table for me

Comment: but all my files will have header, thats why i have to skipped the first row..., i actually dont get the 309 position

Comment: The problem is in your data probably. Could you solve it completely?

Answer (score 2):

I used csvkit to clean my file and after that, i was able to load it successfully in bigquery

Answer (score 0):

The error

`- Error while reading data, error message: Error detected while parsing row starting at position: 309. Error: Bad character (ASCII 0) encountered.`

indicates that the header row contains the 0 byte, to be precise at the 309th byte of the file. 0 bytes are not expected in a CSV file. You can inspect the file with a hex editor. You can probably use `vi` as well.

Since removing the header line fixes the problem, the 0-byte is probably in the header line. I guess it is the last byte of the header, right before the newline character(s).